# How do I determine if an array contains all the integers in a separate array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, contains

I'm in my schools ap computer science class and I'm stuck on this one problem. and cant really even really come up with an idea on how to solve it.

Here it is word for word:
Write a static method named `contains` that accepts two arrays of integers a1 and a2 as parameters and that returns a boolean value indicating whether or not a2's sequence of elements appears in a1 (true for yes, false for no). The sequence of elements in a2 may appear anywhere in a1 but must appear consecutively and in the same order. For example, if variables called list1 and list2 store the following values:

```
int[] list1 = {1, 6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8};
int[] list2 = {1, 2, 1};
```

Then the call of `contains(list1, list2)` should return true because list2's sequence of values `{1, 2, 1}` is contained in list1 starting at index 5. If list2 had stored the values `{2, 1, 2}`, the call of `contains(list1, list2)` would return false because list1 does not contain that sequence of values. Any two lists with identical elements are considered to contain each other, so a call such as `contains(list1, list1)` should return true.

You may assume that both arrays passed to your method will have lengths of at least 1. You may not use any Strings to help you solve this problem, nor methods that produce Strings such as Arrays.toString.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

also here's one attempt i came up with but it doesn't have a sufficient number of tests

```
public static boolean contains(int[] set1, int[] set2) {
    boolean contains = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < set2.length - 1; a++) {
            if (set1[i] == set2[a] && set1[i + 1] == set2[a + 1]) {
                contains = true;
            } else {
                contains = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return contains;
}
```

Comment: In the first loop, be careful of Out of Bounds, `i < set1.length - set2.length`, since you're matching up set1[i+1], if i is the last index, your program will crash. Otherwise you're basically on the right track.

Comment: You need one loop where you are trying to compare one array against the other.  When you find a match you look for the next value. If you get to the end of the second array, you have a match, if you get to the end of the first array, you fail.

Answer (score 2):

For consecutive

```
public static boolean contains(int[] set1, int[] set2) {
     OUTER:
     for (int i = 0; i < set1.length - set2.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < set2.length; j++) {
             if (set1[i + j] != set2[j])
                  continue OUTER;
         }
         return true;
     } 
     return false;
}
```

---

To avoid a label you can use a method which might be clearer

```
public static boolean contains(int[] set1, int[] set2) {
     for (int i = 0; i < set1.length - set2.length; i++)
         if (!matches(set1, i, set2))
             return false;
     return true;
}

public static boolean matches(int[] set1, int off, int[] set2) {
     for (int j = 0; j < set2.length; j++)
         if (set1[off + j] != set2[j])
               return false;
     return true;
}
```

---

If it only needs to be in order

```
public static boolean contains(int[] set1, int[] set2) {
     for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < set1.length; i++)
         if (set1[i] == set2[j]) 
             if (++j >= set2.length)
                 return true;
     return false;
}
```

Comment: @crush Agreed, which is why the consecutive check is better.

Comment: A decent use case for labels hah.

Comment: Just wondering, is the use of labels still considered good? I always knew java had no real support for `goto` (apart from reserved keyword), but in double loops I have ended up using specific break variables to do exactly this.

Comment: @abiessu Yep, `}` should go before the `return false;`

Comment: @TwoThe you could even show us how it is done without a label.

Comment: @TwoThe: that's rather arrogant...  Just because 99.999999...% of them are not necessary and are buggy...

Comment: Btw I find it interesting that the (currently) top-most answer has one solution which wouldn't be considered ok from a language perspective (jump) and two solutions that don't work.

Comment: @TwoThe What is wrong with the second solution? The last solution only applies if the constraints were different.

Comment: As simple as: it returns false in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive way to do this:

```
public static boolean contains(int[] set1, int[] set2) {
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set1) + " " + Arrays.toString(set2));

    //set 2 cannot be contained within set 1 because there aren't 
    //enough elements. This either means that we recursed too deep
    //within the first set that there are not enough elements, or
    //there were not enough elements to begin with.
    if (set1.length < set2.length) return false;

    //from the start of each set, count the number of matches in order
    int numMatched = 0;
    while (numMatched < set2.length && set1[numMatched] == set2[numMatched]) {
        numMatched++;
    }

    if (numMatched == set2.length) 
        //the number of matches found equals the length of the set to
        //search for, so we have found a match. Return true to unravel
        //the recursion.
        return true;
    else {
        //we didn't find a match, so shift the array by 1 and then
        //recursively call this function to compare again.
        int[] subset = Arrays.copyOfRange(set1,  1,  set1.length);
        return contains(subset, set2);
    }

}
```

Each time we fail to find the matching sequence, we create a subset of the array, excluding the first element, and pass that back to contains to continue the checks.Here is an output of each iteration:

First time: set1 =
[1, 6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8] and set2 = [1, 2, 1]
No match is found at the beginning of the array (we break out when comparing 6 and 2. The next recursive call is this:

set1= 
[6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8], [1, 2, 1]

the next recursion compares [2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8] [1, 2, 1]

and so on until the final recursion compares:
[1, 2, 1, 8] [1, 2, 1] and finds the match in order.

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes alot more sense to use the while loop then to try and test individual values.

Comment: While this is an interesting solution, there is a lot of unnecessary memory copying happening.

Comment: @TwoThe there is a lot of memory copying, which definitely would cause problems for large sets. In C++, I would probably use pointer arithmetic or an optional input variable for the offset or a static variable within the function. These aren't available in Java, and the assignment didn't mention additional variables. So short of creating two functions, one with 2 inputs and one with 3, or defining a class within this function that does the same thing, how could this be altered to avoid array copies and still maintain the recursion?

Comment: Beside my answer below, one question: what is the difference between C++'s `*(pArray + index)` and Javas `array[index]` ?

Comment: In C++, I could accept a pointer as the input parameter, and then when I recursively call the function I could pass in a pointer to the element at address pArray + 1, rather than copying the array. Of course using a pointer would cause additional problems with determining the length of the actual array, but that's a different issue, and I would probably use a static function variable to avoid it. The method you went with is non-recursive, but since there were plenty of those solutions, I wanted to illustrate another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `int first=list2[0];` then find that number in `list1`.  Next, loop over all values in `list2` and simultaneously loop through `list1` from the previously-found position until either the entire `list2` is verified present in `list1` or a discrepancy is found.  Restart with `first` after the previously-found location if a discrepancy is found.

Shamelessly copying another answer with a tweak:

```
public static boolean contains(int[] set1, int[] set2) {
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
        if (set1[i] == set2[j]) {
            if (++j >= set2.length)
                return true;
        }
        else {
            i -= j;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This consecutive-version mechanism also ensures that no overruns occur without any extra checks.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that as far as the mentality, you should think "work the first element against the array until a match".

```
public static boolean contains(int[] set1, int[] set2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
       int count = 0;
       for (int w = 0; w < set2.length; w++) {
          if (set2[w] == set1[i + w]) {
              count++;
          } else {
              count = 0;
              continue;
          }
       }
       if (count == set2.length) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
```

In this sense, you will only advance as far down your second array for comparison as needed. If, after going through all the elements in `set2`, you end up with the same length, then it's contained within `set1`. And of course, ask if you have questions :)

Answer (score 1):

[Demo of this answer at IDEOne.com](http://ideone.com/JlRNyU)

I came up with the following function. Read the comments to understand the logic behind it:

```
public static boolean contains(int[] a, int[] b) {
    //Loop until there aren't enough elements left in a to match b.
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - b.length + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {

            //If the jth element of b doesn't match
            //the corresponding element of a, then move
            //to the next step in the sequence.
            if (a[i + j] != b[j])
                break;

            //If we are at the end of the loop, return
            //true because that means we found a consecutive match.
            if (j == b.length - 1)
                return true;

        }
    }

    return false; //If we got here, there are no matches.
}
```

Comment: Err... looking for `1 2 1` in `1 1 1 1 1 1 1` will cause this error while inside the inner loop...

Comment: @abiessu I can just check for `i < a.length - b.length + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it and came up with this solution:

```
static boolean contains(final int[] list1, final int[] list2) {
  final int limit = list1.length - list2.length + 1; // we do not need to check an index >= limit, because list2 wouldn't fit anymore at this point

  for (int indexL1 = 0, indexL2 = 0; indexL1 < limit; ++indexL1) {
    while (list1[indexL1 + indexL2] == list2[indexL2]) { // check all matches from here
      ++indexL2;
      if (indexL2 == list2.length) { // if all of list2 matched so far, we found it
        return true;
      }
    }
    indexL2 = 0; // we did not find it, start from beginning of list2 again
  }

  return false; // no match found
}
```

I call it the Lawrey-Solution.

Comment: +1 For an answer. Are you sure this is the simplest solution?

Comment: Is all this complexity really better than not using a label?

Comment: A for loop + a while loop, not sure if this is overly complex. If this is the simplest/fastest I don't know, but it works without labels, memory copies or other fancy stuff.