# How to check if the sequence of elements of an array appear in another given array?

Tags: java, arrays

So, the question goes as follows:

Write a method that accepts two arrays of integers `a1` and `a2` as parameters and that returns a boolean value indicating whether or not `a2`'s sequence of elements appears in `a1` (if true prints “yes”, otherwise print “no”). The sequence of elements in `a2` may appear anywhere in `a1`. For example, if variables called `list1` and `list2` store the following values:

```
int[] list1 = {1, 6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 8}
int[] list2 = {1, 2, 1}
```

Then your method should return true because `list2`'s sequence of values {1, 2, 1} is contained in `list1`.

You may assume that both arrays passed to your method will have lengths of at least 1. You may not use any Strings to help you solve this problem, nor methods that produce Strings such as `Arrays.toString`.

What I've done so far:

```
public static boolean itAppears(int[] A, int[] B)
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < A.length; j++)
            if(B[i] == A[j])
                count++;

    if(count == B.length)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I'm having some trouble with this code because it's not giving me the needed output. I know where the problem is though. For example, in the given example the first element of `list2` (which is 1) appears in `list1` 4 times, so the count gives 4, which is not equal to the length of `list2`, therefore the output is giving me no. But I'm absolutely clueless on how to fix it so if someone can give me some hints it would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the order of the elements in list1 have to match the order in list2?

Comment: I think It has already been answered, take a look of [this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466924/how-do-i-determine-if-an-array-contains-all-the-integers-in-a-separate-array)

Comment: Looks like the same problem was assigned a year later!

Comment: Yes. If list2 is {1, 2, 3} it must appear in list1 in the same sequence, but can appear anywhere in the array.